# flag_shih_tzu gem , return same value for any key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

im using **flag_shih_tzu** gem and at my `User` model I include that lines

```
include FlagShihTzu
has_flags  2 => :admin,
           3 => :moderator
```

I have a column `flags` as well in User table :

```
t.integer "flags", default: 1, null: false
```

but when I set `flags` value to `2` or `3` it doesn't matter. It will always return me the same value `admin?`. For example:

```
user = User.first
user.flags = 2
user.save 

User.first.admin? 
# => true 

user = User.second  
user.flags = 3
user.save

User.second.admin?
# => true
User.second.moderator?
# => false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes! I find the answer, I was assigned the Raw integer value like 2 & 3

it should  be like `user.admin = true`